# Creating a Fast Exponent Function

Tags: algorithm, ocaml, divide-and-conquer, exponent

I'm having trouble finding a quicker version of the typical exponent function in OCaml. Here are some guidelines that I'm trying to follow:

1. Rather than the typical recursive exponent version of `expt b n ==> b * (b * (b ...)` this function receives two arguments b and n and basically takes a divide and conquer stance.
2. If n is even, then `fastexpt b n => (b ^ (n / 2))^2` else if n is odd then `fastexpt b n => b * (b ^ (n - 1))`

Here's the code that I have written so far:

```
let fastexpt : int -> int -> int
= fun b n ->
    if n = 0 then 1
    else if ((n mod 2) = 0) then (expt b (n / 2)) * (expt b (n / 2)) 
    else b * (expt b (n - 1));;
```

My question is: Is there a way to write this function without using the `expt` function?

Comment: Use `fastexpt` instead?

Comment: Perhaps I don't understand the OCaml language too well, but if I were to include fastexpt then wouldn't I have to make the initial definition of fastexpt as "let rec"?

Comment: @Sean, from https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask :
**Post the question and respond to feedback

After you post, leave the question open in your browser for a bit, and see if anyone comments. If you missed an obvious piece of information, be ready to respond by editing your question to include it. If someone posts an answer, be ready to try it out and provide feedback!**
Please, when you ask a question, accept answers and answer to comments or answers. All your questions have no accepted answer which is strange. Don't be rude, people are here to help, don't leave and communicate.

Comment: @Lhooq Thanks for the tip! I actually should have been more communicating and taken more care regarding the community. I'll be more attentive from now on. :)

Comment: That's a good thing. Thanks for understanding. ;-)

Comment: @Sean You should go through your old questions and mark answers as accepted too. It signals to the rest of the community that this question is "done". See a list of your questions here: https://stackoverflow.com/users/7766024/sean?tab=questions

Comment: Thanks for the link @glennsl . I was actually going through my questions, and I hadn't realized how many I just "threw" out there. I'll take care of them asap. :)

Comment: Hence my comment, I went through your old questions. :-D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're doing here is using the divide and conquer method the first time and then using the normal one for the rest of the computation (if we consider that you already declared `expt`)

Another thing is that if `n` is odd, you can return `b * b^((n-1)/2) * b^((n-1)/2)`, that's the purpose of the fast exponentiation.

What you should do is just defining `fastexpt` as recursive and use it all the way :

```
let rec fastexpt : int -> int -> int
= fun b n ->
    if n = 0 then 1
    else 
      let b2 = fastexpt b (n / 2) in
      if n mod 2 = 0 then b2 * b2 
      else b * b2 * b2;;
```

Comment: If you are trying to have a fast exponential, you may try to avoid `mod` and divisions since they are slow instructions on CPU. Instead, you can use bit shift operations for integer division by a power of 2, and use bit operations to test the parity of the number : if the 1st bit is set to zero, the number is even. However, it is possible that the OCaml compiler already does these optimizations but it is worth trying.

Comment: Yes, thank you, I was actually answering from an algorithmic point of view but your point is worth noting. ;-)

Comment: @AnthonyScemama The compiler does those optimizations. If you want optimality, there may be dark magic to ensure your integers are kept unboxed during the calculation (though I'm not sure it's manually doable).

Comment: @Patj OK, great! Thanks for the precision.